# IEWebDriver Selenium.NoSuchElementException C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Objective: Click on "Loans" link on a site "http://sdettraining.com" using Selenium IEWebDriver and C#.

Symptoms: When test is run, IE 11 browser opens and navigates to "http://sdettraining.com", but does not click link "loans". Test Failed with the following error:

```
Test Name:  IEWebDriver_Test
Test FullName:  NUnitTestFramework.IEWebDriverTest.IEWebDriver_Test
Test Source:    [...]\Selenium\NUnitTestFramework\IEWebDriverTest.cs : line 16
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:08.4

Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByXPath(String xpath)
at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClasse.<XPath>b__c(ISearchContext context)
at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
at NUnitTestFramework.IEWebDriverTest.IEWebDriver_Test() in [...]\Selenium\NUnitTestFramework\IEWebDriverTest.cs:line 33
Result Message: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@id='navbar-collapse']/ul[1]/li[3]/a
```

System Notes: using Windows 10, IE11 with IEWebDriver x32 2.53.0 (I have also tried: x32: 2.48.0 and 2.52.0; and x62 2.53.0). Windows update KB3025390 is not installed.

IE11 Troubleshooting Notes: IE11 is at 100% Zoom and set to open as full-screen. IE11 Security in all zones have been set and tested with the following settings:

- All zones at Medium (except Restricted Sites) and Enable Protected Mode ON
- All zones at Medium (except Restricted Sites) and Enable Protected
  Mode OFF
- All zones at High and Enable Protected Mode On
- All zones at High and Enable Protected Mode OFF

I have also tried the test with Internet Options > Advanced > Allow active content to run in files on My Computer* check and unchecked.

Source Code Troubleshooting Notes: Also cannot find element by LinkText on IE11, but is found on FF. The test Pass on Firefox with Firefox Webdriver.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;

namespace NUnitTestFramework
{
    class IEWebDriverTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void IEWebDriver_Test()
        {
            //Declarations
            IWebDriver driver;
            string URL;

            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"[...]\IEWebdriver\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.0");
            //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            URL = "http://sdettraining.com";

            // 1. open browser nav to site http://sdettraining.com/        
            Console.WriteLine("About to open IE and navigate to site");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
            Console.WriteLine("Arrived at the desired page");

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            // 2. click on Loans link
            Console.WriteLine("About search for the Loans link and click");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='navbar-collapse']/ul[1]/li[3]/a")).Click();
            //driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Loans")).Click();            
            Console.WriteLine("Loans link has been clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

If IEWebDriver just cannot find elements in IE11 on Windows 10, is there a workaround?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you try to use CSS rather than XPath?

Comment: I just tested it on IE11 / Windows 8 with the latest driver and updates and the link is correctly clicked.

Comment: @FlorentB. I was wondering what suggestions you may have on how I may change my setup to get this to pass on my machine. Is there any other information I can provide?

Comment: @SlavKurochkin as I could not get the CSS to work for testing at the site I tried changing URL = "https://en-gb.facebook.com/login"; and driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#loginbutton")).Click(); . It worked on Firefox but not in IE.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you can do:

- First, make sure that you have all the security updates.
- Then reset all the settings (Internet Options > Advanced > Reset)
- Restart IE, select "Use recommended settings" and close IE
- Copy the following registry settings in a `.reg` file and run it:

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN]
  "iexplore.exe"=dword:000000
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE]
  "iexplore.exe"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE]
  "iexplore.exe"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
  "Isolation"=-
  "Isolation64Bit"=-
  "Check_Associations"="no"
  "FormSuggest PW Ask"="no"
  "FormSuggest Passwords"="no"
  "NoProtectedModeBanner"=dword:00000001
  "Use FormSuggest"="no"

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Zoom]
  "ZoomFactor"=-
  "ResetTextSizeOnStartup"=dword:00000001
  "ResetTextSizeOnZoom"=dword:00000001
  "ResetZoomOnStartup"=dword:00000001
  "ResetZoomOnStartup2"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Download]
  "CheckExeSignatures"="no"
  "RunInvalidSignatures"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Activities]
  "NoActivities"=dword:00000001
  "NoOOBActivities"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\New Windows]
  "PopupMgr"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Privacy]
  "ClearBrowsingHistoryOnExit"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete]
  "AutoSuggest"="no"

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
  "WarnonBadCertRecving"=dword:00000000
  "WarnonZoneCrossing"=dword:00000000
  "WarnOnPostRedirect"=dword:00000000
  "PrivacyAdvanced"=dword:00000001
  "CertificateRevocation"=dword:00000000
  "SyncMode5"=dword:00000003

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Url History]
  "DaysToKeep"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\0]
  "2500"=dword:00000003
  "1A10"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1]
  "2500"=dword:00000003
  "1A10"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2]
  "2500"=dword:00000003
  "1A10"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3]
  "2500"=dword:00000003
  "1A10"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\4]
  "2500"=dword:00000003
  "1A10"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Cache]
  "Persistent"=dword:00000000

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WinTrust\Trust Providers\Software Publishing]
  "State"=dword:00023e00
  ```

Note that it can be reversed by resting the settings in "Internet Options" since it only set the current user.

I would also set-up the VS project to build on an x86 platform and not ANY.

If it still doesn't work, you could also try to reinstall IE in "Turn Windows features on or off".

Comment: I tried the above and it did not work for me. Due to other actions, I reset my computer to factory which then IE was able to find the element but was still unable to Click(). I later learned that IE webdriver does not Click() for some, thus I used SendKeys to send the Enter button.

Comment: Has anyone else been able to resolve this?  I am about to throw my hands up with this Windows 10 VM and just start from scratch since our IE executions stopped working.  I've also tried so many various suggestions without any success.  The browser launches and navigates to URL but after that point, selenium is unable to identify any web elements.